# What does the '<-' do in scala?

Tags: scala

I'm new to the language and trying to figure out how to read some of the code in it. Here is the example code that I'm trying to figure out:

```
lazy val genHeap: Gen[H] = for{
    n <- arbitrary[A]
    h <- frequency((1,value(empty)),(9,genHeap))
} yield insert(n,h)
```

I don't quite understand what is going on:

- The return type is `Gen`?
- Does the `<-` act as an `=` operator?
- Is the yield statement building a heap with each iteration by inserting a new element?

Comment: Hi. You probably want to start here: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hello fellow Coursera student! The Principles of Reactive Programming Course is not exactly the easiest place to start to learn Scala! It is an advanced Scala course.

> The type return is a Gen?

Yes, that's what the `:` means. (The `Gen` itself is an object, a random generator to be precise, which can produce a sequence of values, each having the same type as its type parameter - in this case, `H`.)

> Does the <- act as an '=' operator?

Not exactly.

> and the yield statement.. as I understand, it is building a heap with each iteration by inserting a new element?

Actually it's a recursion, not an iteration... but essentially, yes.

A for..yield expression is a fancy way to write a series of `map`, `flatMap` and `withFilter` invocations. Let's desugar it down into ordinary Scala code:

```
lazy val genHeap: Gen[H] = arbitrary[A].flatMap(n => frequency((1,value(empty)),(9,genHeap)).map(h => insert(n,h)))
```

So a `H` generator (`genHeap`) is one that starts by generating an arbitrary `A`, then generating an arbitrary `H` (an empty `H` with probability 0.1, or the result of invoking `genHeap` itself again with probability 0.9), and then inserting the `A` into the `H` to get a new `H`.

These `A`s and `H`s are both abstract types, by the way.

Yes, I'd say this is *pretty advanced stuff*. If you don't even know what `:` means, you're definitely starting in the wrong place.

Comment: Actually even when you have followed the first course you can be totally lost in this exercise...

Comment: Is the arbitrary[A] here something akin to a Stream? And does the function recursively call genHeap until it hits an empty, and build the heap from there?

Comment: @Allen Wang `Arbitrary[A]` is an imperative statement which generates a random value of type `A` using the implicit `Gen[A]` in scope. You can think of it as conceptually like popping the next random value from an infinite stream of random values if you like. And yes, `genHeap` is a recursive value that "calls itself" until it hits an empty - which is why its definition must necessarily involve laziness - in this case, the laziness comes from the fact that it is defined as a `lazy val`.